# Facebook Open Graph custom object hierarchy

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I've created two new Open Graph object types TypeA and TypeB. TypeA has many TypeBs. I have an action ActionA that can be taken on TypeA. When ActionA is taken on a TypeA, the TypeA instance has many TypeBs. These TypeB instances are not showing up in the Open Graph (Facebook is not scraping these pages, and when I see the objects in a news feed, the TypeB objects are not present). Do I need to create these TypeB instances in the Open Graph before I reference them? If so, how do I create them?

EDIT 1:

I've found that when I ask FB to re-scrape the TypeA page, I'm able to see the TypeB instances in the news feed. Looks like there may be a race condition? I've verified that when I notify FB of my TypeA instance, the TypeA page is available and the TypeB pages are available.

Answer (score 0):

> These TypeB instances are not showing up in the Open Graph (Facebook is not scraping these pages, and when I see the objects in a news feed, the TypeB objects are not present)

Why should they be – if you haven’t taken any specific actions on them?

Comment: I've referenced them from a TypeA instance. Maybe that's not enough?

Answer (score 0):

Try linting them to force a Facebook refresh of them?

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug